# Properties of Linearity in Cauchy Functions

Tags: functions

Consider functions through the origin $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow
 \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x,y \in 
 \mathbb{R}.$

I want to try to figure out if these functions are
    linear in scalar multiplication, i.e. $\forall \lambda \in 
 \mathbb{R}. f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x).$

I have an intuition
    that this should work, since $f(x+x) = f(x) + f(x) = 2f(x)
 \implies f(2x) = 2f(x).$ This would imply that $f(3x) =
 f(2x + x) = f(2x) + f(x) = 2f(x) + f(x) = 3f(x).$ I'm wondering
    if someone could help me on the induction step of this problem.

Comment: this is a [well known problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).  You don't have enough information to deduce that $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$ for *real numbers* $\lambda$.  However, you *can* show that $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$ for *rational* numbers $\lambda$.

Comment: You need contintuity for $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ to hold.